# Unable to get environment variable in node.js

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I want to insert GTM code in my index.html file. And that code should execute only in prod environment of my website

My index.html file

```
<head>
<link rel="import" href="ftl/gtm.ftl">
</head>
```

The content of my gtm.ftl file is below ->

```
<script>
var config = require('./config').server;

var env =config.env;
console.log(env);
    if (config.env && config.env=='PROD'){
            (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push(
            {'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'}
            );var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM');

         }else{
                console.log("helloo");
         }

</script>

<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

I want to load google tag manager script only in prod environment . Issue is not able to read config.env variable in ftl file.

My server.js file

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  api_base_url  : process.env.API_BASE_URL ? process.env.API_BASE_URL :'http://localhost:8080',
  port          : process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT :8000 , 
  env           : process.env.ENV ? process.env.ENV :'DEV',
};
```

How to get this env variable in ftl file.

Instead of using ftl file I tried using javascript as well.

```
<head>
<script src="ftl/gtm.js"> </script>
</head>
```

In my server.js file

```
var express = require('express'); // call express
var app = express(); // define our app using express
var config = require('./config').server;
var env = config.env;

app.set('env' ,env);
```

Now in my ftl/gtm.js i am doing below ->

```
 <% if (env && env =='PROD') { %>
        console.log("Please load for PROD");    
        <% }else{
             console.log("hellllooooo");
           } %>
```

My requirement is just add if condition..based on certain variable. The value of variable comes from node.js process.env variable. Based on that I want to load a script in browser.

I am new to node. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the file is called server.js you need to use require('./server') Or do you have another file called config.js?

Comment: No..i have only server.js file. But still I am getting error 'require is not defined'

Comment: Are you running this in the browser or in node.js?

Comment: i m running in node.js

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have mentioned dot in front of env file.  Like .env